# Syncing open file changes with Visual Studio Code and Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vi

I am looking to auto-sync the file changes for an open file on Visual Studio Code and the same file open externally with Vim.  (i.e.: When the file is changed in Vim, I'd like for it to immediately sync in Visual Studio Code).  I have tried an extension called 'File Watcher' with no luck.

Comment: Isn't it already synced?

Comment: VS Code already watches for external changes and follows them as long as there are no conflicts. Vim by default prompts to load the changes from disk. I don't get it. what do you want to change?

Comment: It doesn't sync instantly, is there a way to have it check for a change much quicker?   It appears that it takes roughly 60 seconds before the sync operation takes effect.

Comment: It syncs near instantly for me on VS Code, and Vim notices the change near instantly as well (I think I have vim configured to check for disk-changes upon focusing it again). If that's not what you're observing, either you're forgetting to save your file manually / or are relying on periodic autosave functions, or the delays are system-based, in which case there may be nothing you can do.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the VS Code command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Please also show the output of the top of `vim --version`.

Comment: ah I actually needed to use this for vim: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/29iq9s/comment/cj5krck/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. Do you have something like that yet in your config? For which application is it not detecting instantly? Vim? VS Code? Both?